# jQuery: rotate image clockwise/counter-clockwise in 90 degree increments?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin that will allow me to rotate an image with smooth animation as it transitions from one angle to another. Can anyone suggest a plugin if there is such a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can look at [jQueryRotate](http://wilq32.adobeair.pl/jQueryRotate/Wilq32.jQueryRotate.html)?